# Client Side People Picker with SharePoint Group

Tags: sharepoint-server, people-picker, clientpeoplepicker

I have come across the client side people picker javascript. Right now the people picker accepts all users. Is there any way we can point it to a SharePoint Group. I only want users that are present in a SharePoint Group to be selected as a value for the people picker. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a attribute `schema['SharePointGroupID'] = 8;`

Full demo:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/clientforms.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/autofill.js"></script>
<div>  
    <label>User Name:</label>  
    <div id="_UserName"></div>  
</div>  
<input type="button" id="button" value="submit">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
    initializePeoplePicker("_UserName");  

});  
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {  
    var schema = {};  
    schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';  
    schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;  
    schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;  
    schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = false;  
    schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;  
    schema['Width'] = '280px';  
    schema['SharePointGroupID'] = 8;
    this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);  
}
$("#button").click(function (){
ensureUser()
})
function ensureUser() {  
var peoplePickerTopDivId = $('#_UserName').children().children().attr('id');  
var peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[peoplePickerTopDivId];  
var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();  
var arryuser = users[0];  
  console.log(arryuser)
} 
</script>
```